# React router v6 createBrowserRouter throwing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' error when importing routes in react application

Tags: reactjs, react-router, vite

I'm facing a syntax error while importing routes to the createBrowserRouter method in main.jsx but not getting this error if I directly place routes.

[image]

```
//main.jsx

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";

import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

import { MainRoutes } from "./Routes/main.routes";
const router = createBrowserRouter(MainRoutes);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

main.routes.js file

```
//main.routes.js

import App from "../App";
import ErrorPage from "../error-page";

export const MainRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
  },
];
```

if I place routes directly to the createBrowserRouter method it's working.

```
//main.jsx

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";

import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./App";
import ErrorPage from "./error-page";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I'm using the below configuration.

```
//package.json

{
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.1",
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
  }
```

Can anyone suggest, what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jsx not js `main.routes.js` change it to `main.routes.jsx`

Comment: It worked, why it happened? in another project I used .js.

Comment: JS just for JavaScript and JSX for JS and Html, idk maybe on another project you change some config in webpack